# Does o365 change the character encoding for incoming messages?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, html-email, exchangewebservices

I use a tool that imports messages from o365 mailboxes. For a year, special characters *(á, é, í, ő, ű)* are displayed incorrectly in the tool, specifically the parts that are imported from the body of the email - anything that comes from the subject line is fine. Of course I assumed that the encoding was off (so not utf-8), but by the time the local IT extracts and sends me the actual message, the body is encoded properly. So my assumption is, that o365 somehow enforces utf-8 somewhere along the way. Is there a way to extract the original message in its original format?

Answer (score 1):

If it was an external message try grabbing the Mime stream https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange. While it isn't stored natively as MIME it should maintain the same encoding see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh545614(v=exchg.140). I'd also suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxbbody/98296160-746e-4b25-8d45-676dabebb57d